# Phantom indestructible file "C:\Program"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-permissions

On a server I have a file just under the **C: root** named "**Program**".
This file **is not visible** in the Windows explorer (configured to show all the files, including the system ones) but I can see it with the `DIR` command.
This file **can't be deleted**, even with an administrator account.

What could I try to get rid of this file?

(*FYI the issue is that this file prevents the MIDL COM compiler from running*)

EDIT: After a reboot a popup appeared proposing to rename the file but it failed because it needs permission from myself!

EDIT: If I type its name `C:\Program` in the Explorer it is completed in the dropdown, so the Explorer can see it, and I can even open it with Notepad++ and change it.
I've tried to delete it via Notepad++ but it can't!

EDIT: Thanks to WinDirStat I was able to open its properties with the standard Explorer popup, and I've changed its security to allow EVERYONE full permissions on it and make EVERYONE the owner.
Now when I try to delete it I get "You require permission from EVERYONE to make changes to this file"!

EDIT: It could be caused by the antivirus software, will check that Monday...

EDIT: I've tried to workaround it with `PendingFileRenameOperations` ([Registry: Delete a File on Reboot](http://blog.notfaqs.com/2007/10/registry-rename-file-on-reboot.html)) without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried to `chkdsk c: /f`?

Comment: When at an elevated command prompt, when you type "RD Program", what's returned?

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for the suggestion but after a planned `chkdsk` and reboot the file is still in the same state.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks, it says `The directory name is invalid.`

Comment: Try using the short-name to rename it: `dir c:\prog*.* /X` find the short version of the name, and then use `ren c:\shortname "c:\new name"`

Comment: It may be that you created this accidentally via a bug in something you were working on and it has invalid string characters in it.

Comment: @Yorik Thanks, but looks like it has no short-name: `25/04/2017  20:21                 0              Program
02/11/2017  19:20    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
05/09/2016  10:23    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   9,233,596,416 bytes free`

Comment: @Yorik its name seems regular but this is a possibility indeed.

Comment: Is it a junction/symlink? `fsutil reparsepoint query c:\program`

Comment: @Yorik No it is not: `Error:  The file or directory is not a reparse point.`